Azure devops build agent failure
I have installed an Azure DevOps server. it works fine but when I set up the build agent for Azure DevOps it fails with this message:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit.

I have examined all settings related to this setting access right by Windows authentication or by PAT, and nothing is working I have installed and uninstalled multiple times the azure devops but the problem still remains

I have seen a couple of these errors to be related to network-connectivity error across servers. In your case this looks like a network connectivity error, where the build agent is unable to establish a connection to the Azure DevOps Server. Are you able to confirm connectivity between the build agent and the Azure DevOps Server by pinging the server? Verify that there are no firewall rules blocking the connection and that the ports are open (the default is 443 for HTTPS).
ping  "Azure DevOps server URL or IP Address
telnet "Azure DevOps server URL or IP Address" 443
These articles discuss similar errors:

Stack Overflow
Microsoft Learn

If this doesn't help, please check the server logs for any errors that might indicate why it is refusing connections and share here.
